# How to reveal Unicodes numeric value property

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

```
'\u00BD' # ½
'\u00B2' # ²
```

I am trying to understand isdecimal() and isdigit() better, for this its necessary to understand unicode numeric value properties.  How would I see the numerical value property of, for example, the above two unicodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the 'numeric value' contained in the character, you could use [`unicodedata.numeric()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.numeric):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.numeric('\u00BD')
0.5
```

Use the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to get the integer codepoint, optionally in combination with `format()` to produce a hexadecimal value:

```
>>> ord('\u00BD')
189
>>> format(ord('\u00BD'), '04x')
'00bd'
```

You can get access to the character property with `unicodedata.category()`, which you'd then need to check against the documented categories:

```
>>> unicodedata('\u00DB')
'No'
```

where [`'No'` stands for *Number, Other*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm).

However, there are a series of `.isnumeric() == True` characters in the category `Lo`; the Python `unicodedata` database only gives you access to the general category and relies on `str.isdigit()`, `str.isnumeric()`, and `unicodedata.digit()`, `unicodedata.numeric()`, etc. methods to handle the additional categories.

If you want a precise list of all numeric Unicode characters, the canonical source is the [Unicode database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/); a series of text files that define the whole of the standard. The [`DerivedNumericTypes.txt` file (v. 6.3.0)](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.3.0/ucd/extracted/DerivedNumericType.txt) gives you a 'view' on that database specific the numeric properties; it tells you at the top how the file is derived from other data files in the standard. Ditto for the [`DerivedNumericValues.txt` file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.3.0/ucd/extracted/DerivedNumericValues.txt), listing the exact numeric value per codepoint.

Comment: I think OP wants 0.5 and 2 for those code points, not their code point.

Comment: @delnan: check, added that too.

Comment: my question may be wrong then - I read about the property values Numeric_Type=Digit, Numeric_Type=Decimal, and Numeric_Type=Numeric I was wondering whether I could produce this property from a unicode point somehow?

Comment: `unicodedata.category('\u00DB') == 'Lu'`, not `No` (it would be true for '\u00BD'). `format(ord('\u00BD'), '04x')` seems unrelated to the question

Answer (score 1):

[the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) explicitly specify the relation between the methods and `Numeric_Type` property.

```
def is_decimal(c):
    """Whether input character is Numeric_Type=decimal."""
    return c.isdecimal() # it means General Category=Decimal Number in Python

def is_digit(c):
    """Whether input character is Numeric_Type=digit."""
    return c.isdigit() and not c.isdecimal()


def is_numeric(c):
    """Whether input character is Numeric_Type=numeric."""
    return c.isnumeric() and not c.isdigit() and not c.isdecimal()
```

Example:

```
>>> for c in '\u00BD\u00B2':
...     print("{}: Numeric: {}, Digit: {}, Decimal: {}".format(
...         c, is_numeric(c), is_digit(c), is_decimal(c)))
... 
½: Numeric: True, Digit: False, Decimal: False
²: Numeric: False, Digit: True, Decimal: False
```

I'm not sure [Decimal Number](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Nd) and [Numeric_Type=Decimal](http://codepoints.net/search?nt=De) will always be identical.

Note: `'\u00B2'` is not decimal because superscripts are explicitly excluded by the standard, see [4.6 Numerical Value (Unicode 6.2)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch04.pdf).

Comment: Neither of the two characters you give is `Decimal`. Can you come up with a third example?

Comment: @Eric here are [*all* decimal numbers (in the Unicode standard used by python executable)](http://ideone.com/JIaSpQ)

Comment: I think I'm confused by how your `is_digit('0')` is `False`

Comment: @Eric `'0'` has  a property `Numeric_Type=decimal` (decimal digit). `is_digit(c)` returns whether `Numeric_Type=digit` (decimal, but in typographic context e.g., `①`) —they are mutually exclusive. What characters have which `Numeric_Type` is defined in the Unicode standard.