# How filter a list for elements that can be converted from strings to floats without raising ValueError?

Tags: python

Say I have the following list

```
w = ['Elapsed', 'time:', '0', 'days', '8', 'hours', '22', 'minutes', '15.9', 'seconds.']
```

I want to filter through this list and only return the elements that can be converted to floats without raising `ValueError`. I could do

```
l = []
for el in w:
    try:
        l.append(float(el))
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

But I was wondering if there is a robust way of using the `filter` and `lambda` functions to achieve the same thing in one line? Or perhpas there's another way?

Comment: Seems good to me. You could also have an auxiliary function that tests whether the string can be converted into float (e.g. check whether all the characters are numbers, etc.) and then use [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter)

Comment: There are ways to do it...including using filter and lambda, but the way you are doing it works and is clear.  #zenofpython.  I do not think there is a more efficient way to do what you seek to do...

Comment: your way is perfectly robust and perfectly pythonic.

Comment: Piling on here: stick with what you have, this is really easy to grok. (If you're using Python 3, you have the option of replacing the `try/except` with `contextlib.suppress`. Doesn't change your approach, just trims out the except/continue.)

Answer (score 1):

### filter way

`l = list(map(float, filter(lambda x: x.replace('.', '', 1).lstrip('+-').isdecimal(), w)))`

### list comprehension way

`l = [float(x) for x in w if x.replace('.', '', 1).lstrip('+-').isdecimal()]`

### isfloat function

```
def isfloat(x: str) -> bool:
    x = x.replace('.', '', 1)    # strip first '.', so we can use isdecimal
    x = x.lstrip('+-')           # strip sign(prosible)
    return x.isdecimal()
```

[the different between str.isdigit, isnumeric and isdecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python)

Comment: I expect this solution to be more expensive, as well as being less Pythonic, than OP's solution. Does the list comprehension or `filter` + `lambda` have *any* benefits?

Comment: just for fun.I perfer use a helper function in list comprehension

Comment: OK. Note it fails for certain strings, e.g. `float('5e6')` works but fails with your method. You also probably meant `x.isdecimal()` instead of `x.is_decimal()`.