# Extract first digit sequence from string containing digits, non-digits and then digits

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, split

I have a column in a Pandas dataframe that contains values as follows:

```
111042345--
111042345
110374217dclid=CA-R3K
109202817lciz@MM10082IA
```

I need to extract just the first sequence of digits in each row - not all of the digits in the row. So the output would be like this:

```
111042345
111042345 
110374217 
109202817
```

I thought the best way to achieve that would be to split the strings by digits and return that but that would give me the unwanted digits after the non-digit characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex `\d` for extract digits, `{,5}` means first 5 digits and `+` is for all digits:

```
df['first_5_digits'] = df['Col'].str.extract('(\d{,5})')
df['all_digits'] = df['Col'].str.extract('(\d+)')
print (df)
                       Col first_5_digits all_digits
0              111042345--          11104  111042345
1                111042345          11104  111042345
2    110374217dclid=CA-R3K          11037  110374217
3  109202817lciz@MM10082IA          10920  109202817
```

Like @ Jon Clements pointed is also possible extract N values by indexing:

```
df['first_5_digits'] = df['Col'].str.extract('(\d+)').str[:5]
```

Comment: While it's nice to show that a regex can be told to match only N many occurrences, I'd probably not use extract twice here but rather use it for `all_digits` then use: `df['first_5_digits'] = df['all_digits'].str[:5]` instead...

Comment: That worked well, just changed it to extract the first 9 digits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by applying [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

In pandas:

```
data = """111042345--
111042345
110374217dclid=CA-R3K
109202817lciz@MM10082IA""".split()

import pandas as pd
from itertools import takewhile

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["numbers"] = df[0].apply(lambda x:''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit,x)) )
print(df)
```

Output (Pandas):

```
                         0    numbers
0              111042345--  111042345
1                111042345  111042345
2    110374217dclid=CA-R3K  110374217
3  109202817lciz@MM10082IA  109202817
```

---

For normal lists:

```
data = """111042345--
111042345
110374217dclid=CA-R3K
109202817lciz@MM10082IA""".split()

print(data)

from itertools import takewhile

d = [ ''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit,text)) for text in data]

print(d)
```

Output (simple lists):

```
# splitted data
['111042345--', '111042345', '110374217dclid=CA-R3K', '109202817lciz@MM10082IA']

# itertools.takewhile
['111042345', '111042345', '110374217', '109202817']
```

---

Edge case:

- if you need negative numbers or decimals you would have to replace [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) with an other (maybe self-written) function that also accepts signs/decimals: see f.e. [What's the difference between str.isdigit, isnumeric and isdecimal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python)

---

Suggested by [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston) because more efficient:

```
df["faster numbers"] = [''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit,i)) for i in df[0]]´
```

( Similar output - other column header )

Comment: In pandas this works much faster than using apply, `df[1] = [''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit,i)) for i in df[0]]`

Comment: @ScottBoston I take your word for it, I am a pandas-cub;)

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using regex:

```
import re
data = """111042345--
111042345
110374217dclid=CA-R3K
109202817lciz@MM10082IA""".split()
output = "\n".join([re.findall('\d+', str(d))[0] for d in data])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
111042345
111042345
110374217
109202817
```