# Extract and round numbers from list of strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, int

I have a Python list that contains strings, integers, and floats

`my_list = [['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']]`

I have been trying to figure out how to:

- remove strings
- round floats and converts them to integers
- remove duplicates

The goal is to return a list that looks similar to the list below

```
new_list = [100, 200, 301, 400]
```

Is this possible and how should I approach this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is there any way to avoid this operation?

Comment: I believe that's a legitimate question. There can be lot of places where it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to remove any alphanumerics and convert rest to rounded int is something like the below:

```
import re

my_list = [['100', '200.1', 'z', '1000_100', '300.9', '400', '100.2']]
my_list_2 = list(set([round(float(x)) for x in my_list[0] if re.fullmatch("[\d\.]+",x) is not None]))
print(my_list_2)
```

> > [200, 400, 100, 301]

A much improved answer thanks to Alexander and Stefan.

Comment: I'd not recommend using regex for that. Numbers can be more tricky than just digits, eg `int('100_000') == 100000`

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have updated answer to accommodate all boundary cases including yours.

Comment: I’ll second what @StefanKögl said, and add that it might be good to replace the list comprehension with a generator expression.

Comment: Why are you using `.search()`? Wouldn’t `.match()` be more appropriate? In fact, the entire matching section is a bit of a mess.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I believe you didn't understand what I was trying to do and thats why I have included comment in my answer to become more readable. You can use re.match or re.search both works. Although I agree that match would be faster. Also for long lists you can compile regex before hand rather than compiling every time in the function to increase efficiency.

Comment: @DevendraSwami can you explain further why you were using `.search()`? I don't think I understand.

Comment: I also don't think we should assume that the input will always be a list which contains a single list.

Comment: If you see above I am using `.match()` as suggested by you since it will not search through entire string if not needed. `.search()` can be used and give similar results but is inefficient. Secondly, I am handling all starting matches which do not match for the entire string by comparing with original string. You can compare their length rather than the string for efficiency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201798/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-devendra-swami).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your question has a list containing a list of strings.

If you actually have a list of strings, omit the `[0]`.

```py
result = []
for item in my_list[0]:
  try:
    v = float(item)
  except ValueError:
    continue
  v = int(round(v))

  if v not in result:
    result.append(v)
```

Then

```py
print(result)
[100, 200, 301, 400]
```

Comment: as you mentioned in comment to my answer, the above answer you posted also include string ('1000_100') as 1000100. Please check my updated answer. Numbers are indeed tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a helper function that lets you convert to an int without throwing:

```
my_list = [['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']]

def make_int(s):
    """
    Convert s to an int, rounding if it is a floating point value. 
    Return None if the conversion cannot be done.
    """

    try:
        return int(round(float(s)))
    except:
        return None

newlist = list(set([i for i in [make_int(s) for s in my_list[0]] if i != None]))
```

This involves two nested list comprehensions:

The inner one converts the list to rounded floats, returning `None` for strings: `[make_int(s) for s in my_list[0]]`

The outer one strips the `None`'s: `[i for i in <inner> if i != None]`

This also removes the need to muck with regexes.

Comment: the above answer you posted also include string ('1000_100') as 1000100 in the answer which should not be the case.

Comment: It isn't stated as part of the question whether underscores are allowed.  Python normally considers them [a legal part of a numeric literal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/)  Since the question just says "integer" and "float", presumably the OP is referring to the Python types.

Answer (score 0):

It's a one liner

```
list(dict.fromkeys(x for x in (round_or_none(s) for s in l) if x))
```

(if, of course, you have defined in advance the `round_or_none` function,

```
def round_or_none(s):
    try:
        return round(float(s))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

that is :-)

Demo:

```
>>> def round_or_none(s):
...     try:
...         return round(float(s))
...     except ValueError:
...         pass
... 
>>> l = ['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(x for x in (round_or_none(s) for s in l) if x))
[100, 200, 301, 400]
>>>
```

---

Without the extra function

```
rounded = []
for s in l:
    try:
         rounded.append(round(float(s)))
    except ValueError:
         pass
rounded = list(dict.fromkeys(rounded))
```

---

This works for Python 3.6 and newer, otherwise use an OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
rounded = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(rounded))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: use [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).

```
from more-itertools import map_except, unique_everseen
my_list = ['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']

intlist = list(unique_everseen(map_except(lambda s: round(float(s)), my_list, ValueError)))
##########################################################################################

print(intlist) #> [100, 200, 301, 400]
```

Here are the docs

- for [unique_everseen](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen);
- for [map_except](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_except).

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is with a "try/catch" and just build the new list from that.

```
my_list = ['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']
new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    try:
        new_list.append(int(float(item)))
    except ValueError:
        pass

new_list = list(set(new_list))
print(new_list)
```

Alternative is to use a list comprehension. Use `round` instead of `int` if you want the rounding and not the truncation.

Comment: I don’t believe this is correct, since the question says that floats should be rounded, whereas your answer removes floats.

Answer (score -1):

The "pythonic" one-liner:

```
a = ['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']
list(set([int(round(float(b))) for b in a if b.isdigit()]))
>>> [400, 100]
```

Comment: The question asked for rounding. Your solution truncates digits after the decimal, and therefor gives a different result.

Comment: `int('11_222')` → `11222`, `'11_222'.isdigit()` → `False`

Comment: Could the `int()` be removed here? I’ll second the comment by@gboffi, and add that unfortunately handling strings that contain numbers [seems complicated as a whole](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44891070/11301900).

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Just because the string to num is complicated it's best to use builtins rather than _ad hoc_ regexes/hacks!

Comment: @gboffi Oh god yes, I wasn't suggesting that regex should be used, don't worry ;)

Answer (score -1):

Simple Answer

```py
my_list = [['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']]
new_list=[]
for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        try:
            num=round(float(j))
            if num not in new_list:
                new_list.append(num)
        except:
            pass
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Checking if every item is in the list doesn't seem efficient, although I would be interested to know how it compares to a set.

Answer (score -1):

mmm in order to solve this, i would use a couple of tricks and a list comprehensions.

```
#with a regex you can define a matching pattern in order to
#clean the list of strings of every alpabetic element

import re
old = ['100', '200.1', 'z', '300.9', '400', '100.2']

# for every element that not match with capitals A to Z, or a to z
# make it a round float into this list.
new = [round(float(x)) for x in old if not re.match(r'[A-Za-z]',x)]
#clean the duplicates and print
print(list(set(new)))
```

Comment: the above answer you posted also include string ('1000_100') as 1000100 in the answer which should not be the case.

Comment: On top of what @DevendraSwami said, this solution fails for a bunch of different inputs. For example: "%", "1$0", etc.

Comment: if you read the comment: "clean list of every alpabetic element". if you wanna include special characters, you can add them to the fillter...

Comment: @Fergdulanto was that in reponse to my comment?

Answer (score -2):

The format of the list isn’t clearly defined. For the sake of this solution, I will assume that the input is a two-dimensional list of strings (A.K.A. a list of list of strings). If your lists follow a different format (multiple levels deep, sublists mixed in with strings, etc.) it is possible that lists are not the data structure you need.

```py
import itertools as itt

def str_to_int(str_in):
    try:
        res = round(float(str_in))
    except ValueError:
        res = None
    return res

def trans_lst(lst_in):
    flat_lst = itt.chain.from_iterable(lst_in)
    parse_res = (str_to_int(item) for item in flat_lst)
    res_lst = list(set((item for item in parse_res if item is not None)))

    return res_lst
```

Comment: just check for input `'1000_100'`. Failing for that.

Comment: @DevendraSwami you’re right, I believe it’s because of `chain.from_iterable()`. I’ll have a solution in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: still believe my one liner can be most pythonic you can get :D

Comment: Actually @DevendraSwami whether or not the input `[“1000_100”]` is valid depends on the question’s requirements. Can the lists contain sublists AND strings, or is it only sublists OR strings. I.e. can there be input like `[“100”, “54.5”, [“hi, “101”], “20.01”], or will it always be of the style `[[“100”, “hello”, “101.0”], [“25”], [[“13”, “%”]]]`.

Comment: I hope that’s clear, it’s tough to explain! I will leave a comment on the question so we can hopefully get some more information from OP.