# Python function not acknowledging my input

Tags: python

I'm working through old exam question papers to figure out how to write a program that will tell you if the weather is hot or cold based the value you enter.

The way I have it, anything below 26 should say cold and anything above should say hot. The problem is everything above 10 is coming back as it's hot. I can't figure how what I'm doing wrong. Any help / advice would be appreciated.

```
temperature = input("What is the temperature? ")

if temperature == "26":
    print("The weather is average")
elif temperature <= "26":
    print("The weather is hot")
elif temperature >= "26":
    print("It's a cold day")

else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Result

```
What is the temperature? 17
The weather is hot
```

Comment: Because you specified `elif temperature <= "26":
    print("The weather is hot")`

Comment: You have to change your elif that use <= and >=, **ALSO** do `temperature = int(input("What is the temperature? "))` and compare to ints, not sting, 26 not "26"

Comment: Your greater-thans and less-thans are backwards.  `elif temperature <= "26": print("The weather is hot")` Why would a temperature _less_ than 26 be hot?

Comment: `if temperature == "26"`. you are comparing with strings. You should compare with numeric types like `int` or `float`. Remove the quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you @azro, that worked! I thought I had tried that but forgot to use "int".

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
temperature = int(input("What is the temperature? "))

if temperature == 26:
    print("The weather is average")
elif temperature > 26:
    print("The weather is hot")
elif temperature < 26:
    print("It's a cold day")

else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Your conditions were flipped. You should also cast the value from the input to int and compare it as int instead of string.

Comment: It certainly needed converting from a string, but from a physical point of view, a float is still more appropriate for a temperature than an int, even if your threshold for comparison happens to be an integer value. A user could reasonably expect to enter 25.3 for example.

Comment: @alaniwi that is true but this is just a toy example.

Answer (score 0):

Your two tests are reversed (you have below 26 hot and above cold)

Comment: That's not the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code as it stands:

1. The equality operators are incorrect.

I would also suggest to not use `=` with both the `<` and `>` operators just to get a better consistency. Especially so when there is a separate case checking specifically for `==`.

2. The problem with comparing the temperature as a string is that it is comparing the values lexicographically. A few examples to explain the issue:

`"14" is less than "67"`

This is right but the problem comes with having different length of the temperature string

`"3" is more than "26" lexicographically` -> The weather is hot

`"100" is less than "26" lexicographically` -> It's a cold day

It is best to make sure that we convert the temperature and compare them as integers.

3. Alphabets are non-num characters are not being handled. I am using `isdecimal()` to check that. ([refer this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912545/4273793))

```
temperature = input("What is the temperature? ")

if not temperature.isdecimal():
    print("Temperature entered '{}' is not an int!".format(temperature))
else:
    temperature = int(temperature)
    if temperature == 26:
        print("The weather is average")
    elif temperature > 26:
        print("The weather is hot")
    elif temperature <= 26:
        print("It's a cold day")

    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

Result

```
What is the temperature? 17
It's a cold day

What is the temperature? 26
The weather is average

What is the temperature? 3
It's a cold day

What is the temperature? 100
The weather is hot

What is the temperature? dsf86
Temperature entered 'dsf86' is not an int!

What is the temperature? 34.23
Temperature entered '34.23' is not an int!
```

Comment: You shouldn't use '=' with '<' operator in your logic. Because equality checking is already done at first if condition.

Comment: This gives tells the user it's cold when it's 100 degrees out.

Comment: Wow, that is a good catch! Currently it compares the strings lexicographically so "100" is lesser than "26". I will change my code to account for this!

Answer (score 0):

Program is working as per the logic written. The logic is wrong. You wanted to print 'cold' if temperature is less than 26. But in the code you have written

```
elif temperature >= "26":
    print("It's a cold day")
```

which means print 'cold' if temperature is greater than or equal to 26 and also you need to compare integers (not strings).

Below is the code

```
temperature = int(input("What is the temperature? "))

if temperature == 26:
    print("The weather is average")
elif temperature > 26:
    print("The weather is hot")
elif temperature < 26:
    print("It's a cold day")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: The problem was 7 and 17 were getting different results. I realized it was back to front which is okay. I was more concerned with two numbers under 26 getting different results

Comment: @Leigh That's because you forgot to convert to `int`.

Comment: I modified the answer. Check it now. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `>` and `<` signs are flipped. It's best to convert the numbers into integers/floats:

```
temperature = int(input("What is the temperature? "))

if temperature == 26:
    print("The weather is average")
elif temperature > 26:
    print("The weather is hot")
elif temperature < 26:
    print("It's a cold day")

else:
    print("Invalid")
```

By the way, with `if temperature == 26:`,

the `=` in `elif temperature => "26":` and `elif temperature <= "26":` will never be used.