# Remove rows from pandas dataframe if string has 'only numbers'

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am looking to remove all rows from the df that have ONLY numbers in the string

Here is an extract of the dataframe

```
                         qid    question_stemmed                                   target   question_length total_words
149952  1d53c9c017999b4f77e2    8430397824532987451912384179815150754023741609...   0              241              3
```

Is there a way i can do that?

I tried the below, but it will remove all rows that have numbers in the string (along with any other datatype). However, i am looking to see if i can remove all 'numeric ONLY' rows.

```
df['question_stemmed'] = df[df['question_stemmed'].str.contains(r'[^a-z]')]
```

Appreciate any help here

Comment: `df = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.match(r'\d+$')]` or `df = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.match(r'[0-9]+$')]`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew i got a better solution for a larger problem from you on the other post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we're only worrying about ASCII digits 0-9:

```
df = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.isdigit()]
```

If we need to worry about unicode or digits in other languages:

```
df = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.isnumeric()]
```

Pandas methods internally call the corresponding python methods. See [What's the difference between str.isdigit, isnumeric and isdecimal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python/44891278) for an explanation of how these functions work.

Comment: thanks , but for some strange, reason, it is assigning the value of **qid** to the **question_stemmed** column. it must be a very silly error. Trying to figure out what is causing this.. Any idea here?

Comment: @Shalin this doesn't do any column assignment, so the issue is likely elsewhere in your code. Not sure as I can't see it...

Comment: it was my error. I applied this `df['question_stemmed'] = df[~df['question_stemmed'].str.isnumeric()]` hence it was reassigning. works fine now. Thanks @cs95