# Python Pandas Remove Rows that has Numbers (not float nor int but like 1.2.3)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this post is similar to this: [Remove rows from pandas dataframe if string has 'only numbers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906472/remove-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-if-string-has-only-numbers)

But my difference is that there are rows that contains numbers (e.g. 3.3.2 etc). I want to be able to remove the rows but I am not sure if they are classified as float or string.

Sample data frame:

| ID | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.3.4 texts here |
| 2 | 3.3.4 |
| 3 | 3.3 |

Desired data frame after removal of rows:

| ID | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.3.4 texts here |

Thank you so much in advance.

Dictionary records:
[{'Name': 'Rural-Lands-Strategy-Final-v2', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Cootamundra-Gundagai', 'Coded Text': 'Action 3.3. On farm trials Allow for trials of small scale agriculture without development consent provided environmental and amenity impacts do not give rise for concern for Council and other agencies. The scale and timeframe must also be agreed to in writing. These uses and circumstances would need to be listed in Schedule 2 of the LEP.', 'Document Title': 'Rural Lands Strategy', 'Council Name': 'Cootamundra-Gundagai', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Economic Development', 'Topic': 'Local food producers'}, {'Name': 'The_Hills_Shire_Council_Annual_Report_2018_-*2019', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\The Hills Shire', 'Coded Text': 'We embed sustainability principles into all areas of our work. This includes sustainable planning, transport, design, food production,', 'Document Title': '2019 THE HILLS SHIRE COUNCIL \nANNUAL REPORT \n2018-19 1 THSC', 'Council Name': 'The Hills Shire', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Metropolitan', 'Domain': 'Sustainability and environment', 'Topic': 'Sustainable food production'}, {'Name': 'TSC10479_Statutory_Annual_Report_2018_2019', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Tweed', 'Coded Text': 'Home Expo \nIn September 2018, more than 600 people attended the sixth annual Tweed Shire Sustainable Living Home Expo held at Kingscliff TAFE. \nNinety per cent of attendees who were surveyed at the expo identified actions they intended to take following the event to improve sustainability at home. Planned actions included steps to reduce waste, increase energy efficiency, improve biodiversity, grow backyard food gardens and save water. At the expo, Mayor of Tweed, Katie Milne launched a $60,000 Tweed Shire Innovative Solutions Grants Program to encourage and support individuals, businesses, schools, organisations and community groups to develop innovative solutions to a range of sustainability challenges in the Tweed. On 16 September 2018, Sustainable House Day was held across Australia, and for the first time, the event included an open house in the Tweed. More than 100 people visited Elwood Farm in Limpinwood to marvel at the sustainable features home designers and owners Len and Robyn incorporated into their sustainable dream home.', 'Document Title': 'Annual Report 2018–2019', 'Council Name': 'Tweed', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Health and wellbeing - Education campaigns and events', 'Topic': 'Festivals with interactive education'}, {'Name': 'Brewarrina Child Care Centre policies', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Brewarrina', 'Coded Text': 'educate children about diversity eg different skin colours, different abilities, different foods', 'Document Title': 'Brewarrina Child Care Centre', 'Council Name': 'Brewarrina', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Health and wellbeing - Education campaigns and events', 'Topic': 'School and childcare settings'}, {'Name': 'Annual-Report-201819_Byron', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Byron', 'Coded Text': 'Refill Here Drinking Fountain Program', 'Document Title': 'Annual Report', 'Council Name': 'Byron', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Health and wellbeing', 'Topic': 'Drinking water access'}, {'Name': 'housing-strategy_Sutherland', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Sutherland Shire', 'Coded Text': 'Sutherland centre is an appropriate location to increase residential density so that more people can benefit from being within walking distance to the station, shops and services. Sutherland is already a favoured housing choice for young people as it is a relatively affordable location that offers excellent public transport to jobs in the city. The housing strategy aims to further increase the number of small dwellings in the centre.', 'Document Title': 'HOUSING STRATEGY', 'Council Name': 'Sutherland Shire', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Metropolitan', 'Domain': 'Social and housing policy', 'Topic': 'Affordable housing'}, {'Name': 'mwrc-adopted-operational-plan-2019-20-sm', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Mid-Western Regional', 'Coded Text': 'TIMEFRAME RESPONSIBILITY 30/06/2021 Review and release land for development as required Suitable land available 30/06/2020 Strategic Planning 30/06/2020 Strategic Planning 30/06/2020', 'Document Title': 'DELIVERY PROGRAM 2017/18 – 2020/21 OPERATIONAL PLAN 2019/20', 'Council Name': 'Mid-Western Regional', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Social and housing policy', 'Topic': 'Affordable housing'}, {'Name': 'Delivery_Program_2018-2021_Jan_2019v2', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\North Sydney', 'Coded Text': 'Support community in the development of community gardens, rooftop and hard surface greening', 'Document Title': 'DELIVERY PROGRAM 2018/19-2020/21', 'Council Name': 'North Sydney', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Metropolitan', 'Domain': 'Sustainability and environment', 'Topic': 'Food gardening'}, {'Name': 'Economic Development Plan PDF - 2015-2020_0', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Bellingen', 'Coded Text': 'Participate in the Annual Mid North Coast Food Forum in partnership with other LGAs to enhance Industry development and commercial opportunities', 'Document Title': 'Economic Development and Tourism Plan 2015 - 2020', 'Council Name': 'Bellingen', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Economic Development', 'Topic': 'Local food initiatives'}, {'Name': 'QPRC_Tourism_Plan*-_2017-2025', 'Folder Location': 'Files\\Queanbeyan-Palerang', 'Coded Text': 'Work with local wineries and produce suppliers to increase the presence and promotion of local wines and seasonal produce available in restaurants and cafes within the region and in Canberra', 'Document Title': 'QUEANBEYAN-PALERANG REGIONAL COUNCIL \nTOURISM PLAN 2017–2025: Supporting the Visitor Economy', 'Council Name': 'Queanbeyan-Palerang', 'State': 'NSW', 'Type of council': 'Regional', 'Domain': 'Sustainability and environment', 'Topic': 'Food chain connections'}]

Comment: You could change the column content to a string and check it with the isalpha() to see if there is letters in the column. Make your decision from there.

Comment: try : ``df.loc[df.Column.str.contains("[a-zA-Z]+$")]``

Comment: @sammywemmy I tried your suggestion but it mentioned:  Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
I did a dropna() before to make sure there are no NA values though

Comment: Kindly share your data as a dictionary `df.to_dict('records')`

Comment: If I made it to a dictionary, then the locator wouldn't work?

Comment: maybe just try: `df.Column.str.contains("[a-zA-Z]")`

it should return a boolean series

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. May I ask though, where do you get the a-zA-Z codes? Like what are they called? Maybe I can give it a look as well? Thanks :)

Comment: it's called "regular expressions". Here's the link to str.contains method by the way: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html?highlight=contains#pandas.Series.str.contains

please provide an example of your dataframe, if it's possible (export it as a dictionary as @sammywemmy mentioned)

Comment: how do i insert dictionary to stack overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform to str then use Regex function.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'value':['3.3.4 text','3.4.5',3.2]})
df=df.astype(str)
df[df['value'].str.contains(r'^[\d.]+$')]
```

It gets:

```
  id  value
1  2  3.4.5
2  3    3.2
```