# (Python) How to extract numbers from a string (without regex)?

Tags: python, string

I would like to extract all the numbers contained in a string. I can't use regex, is there any other way?

Example:

```
minput = "BLP45PP32AMPY"
```

Result:

```
4532
```

Comment: I'm curious why you can't use regex.  The `re` module is built in.

Comment: I'm writing a program on a website that can't import other libraries. (I think it's probably a compiler problem) I can only use basic commands.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "other libraries".  If it was something you had to install separately I'd understand, but the `re` module comes as part of Python.  `import re` should work just as well as `import sys`.

Comment: Oh! It is available. I previously tried to import pandas/numpy and ran into a problem. So I avoid all imports. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str.isnumeric`:

```py
minput = "BLP45PP32AMPY"

number = int("".join(ch for ch in minput if ch.isnumeric()))
print(number)
```

Prints:

```
4532
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final_integer = int("".join([ i for i in minput if i.isdigit()]))
```

Comment: Interesting that there appears to be two string functions that do exactly the same thing.  Kind of breaks the rule from [PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: They aren't exactly the same - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python)

Comment: Thanks @sj95126, that was fascinating.  I still say it breaks the Zen of Python though.