# Python program for upper, lower, numbers and combination

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program that user input a random text, and it will print out if it has lower letter, upper letter and/or numbers.
When ever i try to input a combination of numbers and letter it won't print.
Could someone help me with it?

```
string = input("write something here: ")
if string.isalpha() and not string.isupper():
    print("Has letter")
if string.isupper():
    print("Has only upper letters")
if string.islower():
    print("Has only lower letters")
if string.isdigit():
    print("Has numbers")
if string.isalpha() and string.isdigit():
    print("Has numbers and letters")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When ever i try to input a combination of numbers and letter it won't print.

An input like `test123` will not print out `Has numbers and letters` because the function `isalpha` is checking if ALL characters are alphabetical (e.g. `abc` but not `abc1`), while the function `isdigit` tests if ALL characters are numeric (e.g. `123` but not `123x`)

The solution here is to use the function `str.isalnum` (is alpha-numeric):

```py
# passes for: abc123, abc, 123
if string.isalnum():
    print("Has numbers and/or letters")
```

Or, if you want to exclude if it has only numbers or only letters:

```py
# passes for: abc123
if string.isalnum() and not string.isdigit() and not string.isalpha():
    print("Has both numbers and letters")
```

Comment: See also: Difference between `isdecimal`, `isdigit`, and `isnumeric`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912545/2111778

Answer (score 1):

It's because functions like isalpha and isdigit will only return True if they contain ONLY letters or numbers.  Not both.

So isalpha("ldshfldhf") will return True, but isalpha("ldshfldhf12") will not return True.

And likewise isdigit("123490") will return True but isdigit("az123490") will return False.

So none of the if statements you have above will return True, so nothing will print.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("enter random text here:")

if string.isalnum():
    print("It is alphanumeric character")
    
    if string.isalpha():
        print("It is alphabet character")
        
        if string.islower():
            print("It is lowercase alphabet character")
        
        elif string.isupper():
            print("It is a uppercase alphabet character")
    else:
      print("It is a digit")
            
elif string.isspace():
    print("It is a space character")
        
        
else:
  print("It is a special character")
```

Comment: Code only answers without any explanation are rarely helpful, and even if the code “should be self explanatory” adding explanation ensures _everyone_ can understand. Please consider [edit]ing your answer to not only include corrected or improved code, but also an explanation of _how_ and _why_ the implementation works. From [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."