# How to check if input is a number, and do something about it if it isn't?

Tags: python

As the title says, I'm trying to make a guessing game for fun. My only problem is figuring out if they did anything besides a flat number (no decimals, negatives, letters). If it is something besides that, it prints something.

```
import random
import time
streak = 0
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]



while True:
  answer = random.choice(numbers)
  insultlist = ["bro the real answer was " + answer + ", how are you even that bad?", "bro you suck at this, u werent even close. The correct answer was " + answer + "..", "it's the people like you who make me question the future of this planet. The actual answer was " + answer + ".", "lol u suck, the real answer was " + answer + "."]
  insultchoice = random.choice(insultlist)

  guess = input("Type a number between 1 and 10! ")


  if guess == answer:
    print("lol ur lucky, you guessed it correctly.")
    streak = streak + 1
    streakmsg = f"You're at a streak of {streak}."
    print(streakmsg)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("______________________________________________________")

  else:
    print(insultchoice)
    if streak >0:
      loststreak = f"You lost your streak of {streak}."
      print(loststreak)
      streak = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    print("______________________________________________________")
```

I tried using type(guess) and isnumeric, but they just ended up printing the same thing even if it is or isnt a number.

Comment: That shouldn't happen with isnumeric. What code did you use?

Comment: Please read [mre] and provide one, nowhere in your example have you tried to qualify the user's response.

Comment: Now that the answer has been accepted, I wonder what was done about the part of the original question "... and do something about it if it isn't?" That did not appear in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the string `guess` is a sequence of decimal digits, and is more efficient than the regex solution.

```
if not guess.isdecimal():
    print("You didn't enter a number")
```

Comment: Does .isNumeric() return true or false for floating-point inputs?

Comment: False, but it seems that's intentional in this case. Specifically, they're only using integers.

Comment: My expectation was the opposite - and this answer (second example)  indicates that floating points return true from isNumeric: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912545/10761353. OP’s stated goal was to be able to flag/reject non-integer inputs.

Comment: If that's the goal, they could just use `not all(i in "0123456789"for i in guess)` or equivalently `not any(i not in "0123456789"for i in guess)`

Comment: How does that stack up runtime wise vs. Regex, or a list comprehension?

Comment: On checking, there's actually two more builtins, `str.isdigit` and `str.isdecimal`, which may be suitable. All of their test cases seem to be positive. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
if re.match("^[0-9]*$", "123"):
    print("Match")
```

it checks that if only contains of number or not, it use regex
and also you can do it in a simple manner:

```
if input().strip() in numbers:
    ...
```

Comment: Regex is notoriously inefficient. Also, they asked if it wasn't numeric, not if it was.

Comment: @Mous If I understood what you mean, we can use a "not" easily... and can you explain why it is inefficient?

Comment: The time complexity of regex is quadratic, plus it requires importing the entire `re` module just to imitate a builtin method. I'll run some tests.

Comment: Your solution takes 1.12 microseconds per loop, whereas the builtin takes 49.9 nanoseconds. That's a 22x difference.

Comment: It is not the best practice to use Regex, because it frequently produces inaccurate results and is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `input()` will always return a string.
From there you need to determine if your string is a valid int.

The most straightforward solution is likely an exact regex match, against a pattern such as `r’[0-9]+’` (matching any character in the 0-9 range, repeated one or more times; even ‘-‘ and ‘.’ would be rejected, satisfying your decimal and negative requirements).

Partial solutions:

1. Conversion with int() in a try/except block, would help you catch non-number inputs, since `int(“A”)` would raise an exception and fall to your except-block, but (e.g.) `int(4.3)` would not fail and simply return `4` (the integer).
2. If `guess.isNumeric()` returns true on floating point numbers, this would also only filter out non-number inputs

_>> EDIT >> _
Now back in front of a terminal, and for the benefit of future searchers (with other answers getting updated), here's some test cases to demonstrate the difference between the builtins:

```py
>>> inputs
['12345', '123.5', 'abc', '123abc', '2²', '-5678']
>>> [v.isdigit() for v in inputs]
[True, False, False, False, True, False]
>>> [v.isnumeric() for v in inputs]
[True, False, False, False, True, False]
>>> [v.isdecimal() for v in inputs]
[True, False, False, False, False, False]
```