# Python: from str to int or float using input()

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following script:

```
1   mylst = []
2   num = input("Enter height: ")
3   
4   if isinstance(num, int) or isinstance(num, float):
5       mylst.append(num)
6   else:
7       print("END")
8   
9   print(mylst)
```

Let's say I have the following heights in cm (**without decimal**): 175, 181, 189

And then I decided to enter heights in inch (**with decimal**): 5.6, 5.9, 6.2

So `mylst` will be `[175, 181, 189, 5.6, 5.9, 6.2]`

I know that the output type of `input()` is always a `str`. And, yes, my script is not a loop. I don't want to change the `input()` into `int(input())` or `float(input())` every time I run the code. I need to use only `if else` statements. No `while` loop, no `try except`, and no `for loop`

So basically, I enter a number, whether it is an `int` or `float`, then it will convert `str` number into `int` or `float`, or stay `str` if the input is a non-number (alphabetic or any character), then it runs through `if else` statements.

I just can't figure it out how to convert the string number to an integer or float number. The `.isdecimal()` doesn't work, it will be considered as a `str` if the number value with a decimal.

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: assuming this is for an assignment, you could check what characters are in the `input()`

Comment: No, it is not for an assignment. I just sat down and thought about it. I tried to do it, but I couldn't because the output type of `input()` is always a `str`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between str.isdigit, isnumeric and isdecimal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python)

Comment: Without using a loop, the list will only ever contain one value, so I don't see how you would ever achieve your desired output...

Comment: do watch out that this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: Of course, I will use it in a loop. But I just wanted to know is there a way with only if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `str.isnumeric()` method for seeing if a string is an integer.

The better implementation would be to use a try/except case.

Code example:

```py
if num.isnumeric():
    mylst.append(int(num))
elif num.replace(".", "").isnumeric():  # best I could think of without using try/except
    mylst.append(float(num))
else:
    # append if string, not sure if this is what is intended
    mylst.append(num)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for values with multiple decimal points

Comment: That's true! That's why I included the comment after the line. It's not a perfect solution and a try/except block would be much better.

Comment: Actually, your script works great! @Chris Good job!
It is working with multiple decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@Chris`, I managed to solve my question and get the same output I would like to get: `[175, 181, 189, 5.6, 5.9, 6.2]`.

As `@John Gordon` said that, we need a loop to have multiple entries of values.
Yes! That was my purpose. To run the code one time and enter multiple values without concerning if it is an integer or a float, or running to an error.

So, here's the code:

```
1   mylst = []
2   
3   num = int(input("Enter number of inputs: "))
4   
5   for i in range (num):
6       n = input()
7       if n.isnumeric():
8           mylst.append(int(n))
9       elif n.replace(".", "").isnumeric():
10          mylst.append(float(n))
11      else:
12          break
13  
14  print(mylst)
```

Thank you guys! You are all awesome!