# What is the difference between unicodedata.digit and unicodedata.numeric?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, cpython, python-module-unicodedata

From [unicodedata](http://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/unicodedata.html) doc:

> unicodedata.digit(chr[, default]) Returns the digit value assigned to
>   the character chr as integer. If no such value is defined, default is
>   returned, or, if not given, ValueError is raised.
>
> unicodedata.numeric(chr[, default]) Returns the numeric value assigned
>   to the character chr as float. If no such value is defined, default is
>   returned, or, if not given, ValueError is raised.

Can anybody explain me the difference between those two functions?

Here ones can read [the implementation of both functions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/unicodedata.c#L107) but is not evident for me what is the difference from a quick look because I'm not familiar with CPython implementation.

**EDIT 1:**

Would be nice an example that shows the difference.

**EDIT 2:**

Examples useful to complement the comments and the spectacular answer from @user2357112:

```
print(unicodedata.digit('1')) # Decimal digit one.
print(unicodedata.digit('١')) # ARABIC-INDIC digit one
print(unicodedata.digit('¼')) # Not a digit, so "ValueError: not a digit" will be generated.

print(unicodedata.numeric('Ⅱ')) # Roman number two.
print(unicodedata.numeric('¼')) # Fraction to represent one quarter.
```

Comment: I believe `numeric` works for other numeric characters besides the arabic numerals, such as DEVANAGIRI ONE, and so on.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could you put an example of the difference pls?

Comment: Judging from types and description, digits are for actual digits, and numeric may process things like vulgar fractions (e.g. ¾).

Comment: @weirdan from the doc is clear that both functions just accept a character as the first parameter.

Comment: Closely related (not sure if dupe or not): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384852/difference-between-unicode-isdigit-and-unicode-isnumeric

Comment: @gsi-frank, what they accept is the same, but they differ in what they **return**

Comment: @weirdan Just a simple example will clarify all this ;) Anybody? None of what I read here so far clear my mind and I think that an example in this situation is the best way to illustrate.

Comment: @weirdan's example of ¾ seems to fit - it's a single Unicode character (codepoint U+00BE) with a numeric value of 3/4 but no digit value.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper You are right. `unicodedata.numeric('¼')` and `unicodedata.digit('¼')` are the examples that illustrate that clearly. Thanks to everybody that bear with this question.

Comment: Will be nice If someone put such example as an answer so other people interested in this questions don't have to read the comment thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

If a character represents a decimal digit, so things like `1`, `¹` (SUPERSCRIPT ONE), `①` (CIRCLED DIGIT ONE), `١` (ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE), `unicodedata.digit` will return the digit that character represents as an int (so 1 for all of these examples).

If the character represents any numeric value, so things like `⅐` (VULGAR FRACTION ONE SEVENTH) and all the decimal digit examples, `unicodedata.numeric` will give that character's numeric value as a float.

For technical reasons, more recent digit characters like  (DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ZERO) may raise a ValueError from `unicodedata.digit`.

---

Long answer:

Unicode characters all have a `Numeric_Type` property. This property can have 4 possible values: Numeric_Type=Decimal, Numeric_Type=Digit, Numeric_Type=Numeric, or Numeric_Type=None.

Quoting the [Unicode standard, version 10.0.0, section 4.6](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch04.pdf),

> The Numeric_Type=Decimal property value (which is correlated with the General_Category=Nd
>   property value) is limited to those numeric characters that are used in decimal-radix
>   numbers and for which a full set of digits has been encoded in a contiguous range,
>   with ascending order of Numeric_Value, and with the digit zero as the first code point in
>   the range.

Numeric_Type=Decimal characters are thus decimal digits fitting a few other specific technical requirements.

> Decimal digits, as defined in the Unicode Standard by these property assignments, exclude
>   some characters, such as the CJK ideographic digits (see the first ten entries in Table 4-5),
>   which are not encoded in a contiguous sequence. Decimal digits also exclude the compatibility
>   subscript and superscript digits, to prevent simplistic parsers from misinterpreting
>   their values in context. (For more information on superscript and subscripts, see
>   Section 22.4, Superscript and Subscript Symbols.) Traditionally, the Unicode Character
>   Database has given these sets of noncontiguous or compatibility digits the value Numeric_Type=Digit, to recognize the fact that they consist of digit values but do not necessarily
>   meet all the criteria for Numeric_Type=Decimal. However, the distinction between
>   Numeric_Type=Digit and the more generic Numeric_Type=Numeric has proven not to be
>   useful in implementations. As a result, future sets of digits which may be added to the standard
>   and which do not meet the criteria for Numeric_Type=Decimal will simply be
>   assigned the value Numeric_Type=Numeric.

So Numeric_Type=Digit was historically used for other digits not fitting the technical requirements of Numeric_Type=Decimal, but they decided that wasn't useful, and digit characters not meeting the Numeric_Type=Decimal requirements have just been assigned Numeric_Type=Numeric since Unicode 6.3.0. For example,  (DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ZERO) introduced in Unicode 7.0 has Numeric_Type=Numeric.

Numeric_Type=Numeric is for all characters that represent numbers and don't fit in the other categories, and Numeric_Type=None is for characters that don't represent numbers (or at least, don't under normal usage).

All characters with a non-None Numeric_Type property have a Numeric_Value property representing their numeric value. `unicodedata.digit` will return that value as an int for characters with Numeric_Type=Decimal or Numeric_Type=Digit, and `unicodedata.numeric` will return that value as a float for characters with any non-None Numeric_Type.