# Correction about list elements in one line (str to int)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, python-3.5

I have something like this:-

```
List = [["a","1"],["b","2"]]
```

and what I wanna do is keep single letter integers as integers.
so output should be like

```
List =  [["a",1],["b",2]]
```

Comment: what is your input and what is output ?

Comment: `output_list = map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], input_list)`

Comment: `output = [[x[0], int(x[1])] for x in list]`

Comment: You might also want to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh my, you completely changed your question.

Comment: What baffles me most here is how this got upvotes...

Comment: Rolled back to original question. Please do not change question, especially not after someone has answered it.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you stored that in a list called "data", you can do the following.

```
new_data = [[k,int(v)] for k,v in data]
```

Refer below for details:

```
data =  [["a","1"],["b","2"]]
new_data = [[k,int(v)] for k,v in data]

print new_data
```

**Output:**

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
```

Comment: One could also suggest using a dictionary `{k:int(v) for k,v in data}` because I have a hunch that's what OP actually wants :)

Comment: @timgeb: Surprise, suprise! :D Look at what OP wants now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Changed question before rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47325984/3): Sort heterogeneous list

It seems that you completely changed your question after people answered the first version. Please don't do that. You could simply ask a new question.

If you want to sort a heterogeneous list, you can provide a custom [key](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) which returns a tuple. The first element is `0` for strings and `1` for integers. This way, the strings would appear before the integers.
If the object is an integer, the second element is set to `-x` in order to sort the integers in decreasing order:

```
def custom_order(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return (1, -x)
    else:
        return (0, x)

print(sorted([1,2,3,4,5,"a","b","c","d"], key=custom_order))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

This code should work on Python2 and Python3. It will fail on Python3 if an element is neither a string nor an int.

## Original question: convert nested strings to ints

You could use a [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18072799/6419007) with a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/6419007) to check if the string [looks like an integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal):

```
>>> data = [["a","1"],["b","2"]]
>>> [[int(s) if s.isdecimal() else s for s in l] for l in data]
[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
```

As a bonus, it would work in any order and with sub-lists of any size:

```
>>> data = [["a","1"],["b","2"],["3", "c"], ["4", "5", "d"]]
>>> [[int(s) if s.isdecimal() else s for s in l] for l in data]
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], [3, 'c'], [4, 5, 'd']]
```

Comment: This will fail with `[['x', '⅕']]`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24384917/7207392).

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Excellent remark, thanks! So `str.isdigit` would be correct, right?

Comment: I'm afraid no, because of digits like '➊'.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: You can break many things with unicode ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ . What about `isdecimal()`?

Comment: `.isdecimal` although it also includes a few unexpected characters seems to work

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you very much, I learned something new today!

Comment: I did rollback to the original version of the question.