# displaying subscript/superscripts in python tkinter listbox with unicode

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter, notation

I need to display some values with subscripts/superscripts in a Tkinter Listbox in Python.

I have managed to get output to display with hardcoded values like so:

```
 listbox.insert(i, (u"C\u2076"))
```

This displays: C<sup>6</sup>

That is the desired output I want; however, the value of 6 needs to be taken from a variable. I can't figure out how to concatenate a variable onto the u"C\u207" portion. If I try building it using a string, it has an escape character and displays like "C\2076", so that didn't work.

How else can I do this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13875688/3275008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out for myself. The comment above was helpful, but I still needed a way to concatenate the unicode characters because I was building a much larger list of characters.

To concatenate the unicode characters, I found pythons built in unicode function.

I returned the superscript like the above linked thread demonstrated:

```
def get_superscript_unicode(n):
    codes = {
        1 : u"\u00B9",
        2 : u"\u00B2",
        3 : u"\u00B3",
        4 : u"\u2074",
        5 : u"\u2075",
        6 : u"\u2076",
        7 : u"\u2077"
    }
    return unicode(codes[n])
```

To concatenate multiple unicode returns, I did something similar to this:

```
for item in list:
    s += unicode(get_superscript_unicode(n)) + unicode(other text)
return unicode(s)
```

I probably have one too many calls to unicode there. I kind of quickly took out the relevant pieces of a much more complicated string being built.