# Is there a non-math version of matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, formatting, latex

I am trying to plot a graph with a logarithmic y-axis using `pgf_with_latex`, i.e. all text formatting is done by pdflatex. In my matplotlib rc Parameters I define a font to be used. Here comes my problem: The standard `matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation` formatter used math text and therefore a math font, which does not fit the rest of the fonts (sans-serif).

How can I format the y-axis labels using a formatter from `matplotlib.ticker` so that I get the labels formatted as powers of 10 with superscripted powers? To be more specific: How do I get these yticklabels formatted the same way but with the font from the xticklabels?

I already tried using different formatters provided by `matplotlib.ticker`, but none of them has the exponents written the way I want.

Here is an example of what I mean with a MWE below.
[image: example plot]

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use('pgf')
pgf_with_latex = {
        "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
        "font.family": "sans-serif",
        "text.usetex": False,
        "pgf.preamble": [
            r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",
            r"\usepackage{tgheros}",  # TeX Gyre Heros sans serif
            r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}"
            ]
        }

mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[3, 2])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.minorticks_off()
ax.set_xlabel("sans-serif font label")
ax.set_ylabel("math font label")
plt.gca().set_ylim([1, 10000])
plt.gcf().tight_layout()


plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format("test"))
```

Caution: A TeX distribution has to be installed on your system to run this. I used MikTex 2.9. Also Python 3.6.2 and matplotlib 2.1.2.

Comment: What is the reason to use `"text.usetex": False,` here? Should that not be `True`?  If you use `\usepackage{tgheros}`  in a latex document, does it affect math font? (i.e. would something like `This is text and $a= \sin{b}$` be printed in the same sans-serif font in a pure latex document?)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I use `"text.usetex": False` because apparently the font loaded in the preamble is only taken into account this way. If I enable the flag, TeX uses Latin Modern. `tgheros` would not affect the math font anywhere. My question is, how can I prevent matplotlib from using a math font while still keeping the labels the same way?

Comment: So essentially you want to achieve something like `$10^{2}$` outside of math mode. I don't know if that is possible. But if you find a way to do it in pure latex,  it would be possible to adapt the formatter accordingly; if not, there is nothing matplotlib can do. I think usually people try to use a math font which looks similar enough to their text font in such cases.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That is exactly what I am trying to do! Maybe somebody knows some kind of workaround...

Comment: I guess that would be a two stage problem. So in order to find a way to produce $10^{2}$ outside of math mode in tex, you might first try to find a solution at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) (either by searching or asking a question there). *If* it turns out to be possible, linking to such solution here would allow to use it for matplotlib formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `LogFormatterExponent` to format the ticks with `"10\textsuperscript{x}"` where `x` is the exponent. This would not use math mode tex, i.e. no `$` signs around the text, and therefore would use the textfont specified in the preamble (in this case the font without serifs).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatterExponent

mpl.use('pgf')
pgf_with_latex = {
        "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
        "font.family": "sans-serif",
        "text.usetex": False,
        "pgf.preamble": [
            r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",
            r"\usepackage{tgheros}",  # TeX Gyre Heros sans serif
            r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}"
            ]
        }
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class LogFormatterTexTextMode(LogFormatterExponent):
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        x = LogFormatterExponent.__call__(self, x,pos)
        s = r"10\textsuperscript{{{}}}".format(x)
        return s

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[3, 2])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LogFormatterTexTextMode())
ax.minorticks_off()
ax.set_xlabel("sans-serif font label")
ax.set_ylabel("text mode tex label")
plt.gca().set_ylim([0.01, 20000])
plt.gcf().tight_layout()


plt.savefig('{}.pdf'.format("test"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own FuncFormatter that does the scientific notation in unicode.

An almost complete converter to superscript was given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875688/4691830). I just added the minus.

Here's an implementation:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from math import log10

SUPERSCRIPTS = dict(zip(u"-0123456789", u"⁻⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"))
def unicode_sci_notation(x, pos):
    """Scientific notation of number with unicode"""
    power = int(log10(x))
    mantissa = x/(10**power)
    superscript = u''.join(SUPERSCRIPTS[c] for c in str(power))
    # Python 2: Use `unicode(power)` instead of `str(power)`.
    if mantissa == 1:
        return '10%s' % superscript
    else:
        return '%.2f x 10%s' % (mantissa, superscript)
formatter = mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(unicode_sci_notation)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

To do it this way, you need to specify coding: utf-8 at the top of your script. If you don't want that, you can escape the unicode characters as explained in the answer I linked.

[image]

Comment: The code example is for Python 2. In Python 3, I had to replace `unicode()` by `str()`, as all string are Unicode by default. Also, `mpl` here is the alias from an import: `import matplotlib as mpl`. After this small edits, it worked great for me!

Comment: Thanks, @mxt3. I updated to the Python 3 version since Python 2 is no longer officially supported.